# Copy and paste data from one a sheet to another sheet, and from second sheet to third using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have requirement, where I need to copy values(not formula) in a sheet cells part of a range to corresponding cells in another sheet and then from second sheet to corresponding cells in third sheet.

for copying data from first two second I am using below code,

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng         As Range
    Dim c           As Range
    Dim dest        As Worksheet


    Set rng = Range("C3:E3")
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        For Each c In rng

        c.Copy dest.Cells(c.Row, c.Column)

    Next c

End Sub
```

Now, I would like to copy from `sheet2` to `sheet3`. I need this specifically from `sheet2`, because my first sheet may have different value than sheet2.

Comment: Instead of using `Copy`, you can do this `dest.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Value = c.Value`

Comment: @Tim Williams   `Copy` used because the cells may have different data later and I need to keep them as separate

Comment: You say "I need to copy values(not formula)", so it's not clear why you're using Copy, unless you mean the cells you're copying have no formulas?

Comment: @ Tim Williams In  beginning, these cells don't have any formula, but I will be one in first sheet, so the data in first sheet will get change. I need those three sheet after that to compare the values and perform different functions..

Comment: `.Value = .Value` only changes the value when the macro runs.  Your issue with changing references doesn't apply @acr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Sheet1 to contain the formulas, but you need Sheet2 and Sheet3 to contain just the values, modify your code to the following:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng         As Range
Dim c           As Range
Dim dest        As Worksheet
Dim dest2       As Worksheet


Set rng = Range("C3:E3")
Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set dest2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

For Each c In rng
    c.Copy
    dest.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    dest2.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next c

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but here it looks like the data is copying from sheet1 to sheet3. But I am looking in the order. sheet1 copy to sheet2, sheet2 copy to sheet3

Comment: Do you want it to copy only the values to sheet2 and then copy only the values from sheet 2 to sheet 3?

Comment: @acr - what difference does that make?  Are you copying different ranges? Otherwise, the end result is the same.

Comment: Here is my current logic : Consider cell 'C3'. Initially, Sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 'C3' will have same data. Now I am running a SUMIFS formula in sheet1 and  pull values in specific cells in sheet1 and SUMIFS will add 0 on all other cells. I want to preserve my old data in sheet1. So if C3 in sheet1 become after SUMIFS function.I will perform a opy from sheet1 to sheet2 again and will do   IF and AND function, which will check if sheet2 c3 is zero, and sheet3 C3 is non-zero, if that matches, I will copy sheet3 C3 value to sheet1 C3

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly you first want to copy the value from sheet1 'C3' to sheet2 'C3'. You then want to copy that value from sheet2 'C3' to sheet3 'C3'. Then you want to run this sub again after the value of sheet1 'C3' changes to have it copy to sheet2 'C3'. Then if sheet2 'C3' is zero and sheet3 'C3' is non-zero, you want it to copy sheet3 'C3' back to sheet1 'C3' and overwrite the formula?

Comment: Correct !!. I got it working now.Thanks for your help..I am marking it as correct answer since you gave the idea to write my own..